# Performing work after ending the request in nodejs + express

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading

I would like to do some CPU processing that the client doesn't need to know about. I was thinking of using the https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads package to do that (convert an audio file from ogg to raw for example).

I am imagining that I can use `res.send(200)` and after that kickstart the worker like this:

```
res.send(200);

var worker = new Worker(function(){
  this.onmessage = function(event) {
    //do conversion here by calling ffmpeg
  };
});
worker.onmessage = function(event) {
  //upload file to S3
};
worker.postMessage('filename');
```

Will this work or express will wait until this function ends to send back the response?
Will this block the event thread? I hope not if I am using webworker - threads.

Comment: Create a Websocket and use your regular http port to trigger the WS which keeps telling the frontend whatever the updates are. It will not be a good idea though in case this application is trying to serve a lot of users at a time

Comment: now as far as your code goes, `res.send` will basically trigger return from this function as that will be a callback and that will not return to current function again.

Comment: I don't want to tell anything to the user.

Comment: if that's the case then keep a web socket between 2 ports. Node runs on a specific port and another specific port will be allocated to the WS. Else you can even trigger a different URL from your code which will do this

Comment: It gonna be a lengthy code and will require you to google a lot. I cannot help you with code here, right now. Sorry about that! But I could definitely help with the process if need be.

Comment: I can make a microservice in that case that is independent

Comment: What operations you intend to do? I'd like to know more. Probably, I can spare a few minutes on this interesting thing

Comment: audio conversion + upload to S3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120919/discussion-between-akshay-khandelwal-and-arisalexis).

Comment: Whether or not this influences the main event loop or not depends entirely upon the implementation of the node-webworker-threads package.  If it truly uses threads or other processes, then you're fine.  If it just appears to use other threads, but is actually just async code in the same process, then it will be getting in the way of you processing other requests.  To be sure it's "out of the way" of the main event loop, you can carry out the work in a child process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Child Process to do this. Have a look at this [Link](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) for more details. To understand the process, check the code below.

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

app.post('/upload/audio', function (req, res) {
    // Some Code here
    // Code to run a child Process

    var ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

    ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => { // This will run the process and keep receiving the logs as and when available (Async process)
      console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
    });

    ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
    });

    ls.on('close', (code) => {
      console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
    });
    // End the Child Process Block
    // All the code above is async and will trigger the send way before any of your processes are completed
    res.send("Success");
});
```

Comment: well, this is just one way.. for that matter, if you write res.send in the end in your code, it'd still work..